# Class design and object references

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture

Here is a very basic example of what I am trying to do.  In reallity there are more relations but not something extreme or memory heavy.

```
public class ClassA : ISomething
{
    public double property { get; set; }
    ...
    public ClassB classb { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB : ISomething2
{
    public double Length { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class MyProject : BaseProject
{
    public IEnumerable<ISomething> ISomethings { get; set; }
    ...
    public IEnumerable<ISomething2> ISomethings2 { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

The issue here is that I have to keep a list of `ISomethings2` and then   `classb` property of ClassA to reference only an existing item in the `ISomething2` list. The hard thing here is that:

- Removing an item from `ISomething2` should remove all references to it (`classb` property of ClassA instances to be set to null)
- Prevent other developers setting `classb` property to a non existing object in list or a new user created object.
- Objects in `ISomethings2` can exist without being referenced.

These classes are used for project description **not database** stuff. Like when you open a project file for an application. So changing a property in classB should be visible to all since it is the same object reference. 
Is there a pattern to achieve what I want without much coupling? Alternative designs/approaches are also welcome.

Comment: This question is way too broad. I can't help you more than to say you should work on narrow down what you're asking.

Comment: Too Broad  that would get opiniated answers ? Probably I could keep the first bullets only

Comment: Ok, edit your question to narrow it down.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `Manager` class, and add some behavior in your classes.

First is the `ManagerClass`

```
public class ManagerClass{
    public IEnumerable<ISomething> ISomethings { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ISomething2> ISomethings2 { get; set; }

    public void RemoveSomething2(ISomething2 something2){
        //iterate through ISomething and remove the ClassB reference
    }
}
```

`ClassA` accept `ManagerClass` constructor, revoke `ClassB` set property.

```
public class ClassA : ISomething
{
    public ClassA (ManagerClass managerClass){
        this.managerClass = managerClass;
    }

    public double Property { get; set; }

    private ManagerClass managerClass = null;
    public ManagerClass ManagerClass { get { return managerClass; } }

    private ClassB classB null;
    public ClassB ClassB { get{ return classB; } }

    public void SetClassB(ClassB classB){
        // check whether 
        if(classB != null && !ManagerClass.ISomethings.Any(k=> k==classB)){
            this.classB = classB;
        }
        // set null
        else if(classB == null){
            this.classB = null;
        }
        else {
            throw new Exception("not found");
        }
    }
}
```

---

Though I prefer a simplified version with relational model.

```
public class SomethingRelation{
    public ISomething something;
    public ISomething2 something2;
}

public class ManagerClass{
    public IEnumerable<ISomething> ISomethings { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ISomething2> ISomethings2 { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SomethingRelation> Relations { get; set; }

    public void RemoveSomething2(ISomething2 something2){
        //iterate through SomethingRelation and remove all the something2 reference
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, personaly I would replace the ClassB object in ClassA with string ClassBId and just have the one list.

BUT! if you want to keep the structure you could make the project ISomething2 enumerable link to the ISomethign1 enumerable. ie

```
    public class MyProject 
    {     
        public IEnumerable<ISomething> ISomethings { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<ISomething2> ISomethings2 {

            get { return this.ISomethings.Select(i => i.classB); }
        }

        public void RemoveSomething(ISomething2 s)
        {
            foreach (var somthing in this.ISomethings.Where(i => i.classB == s))
            {
                somthing.classB = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: For removing this could work however for enumerating it wont because they could be defined alone.

Comment: yes, you really need it to make your own IEnumberable implementation if you want to do proper adding and removing etc. However, you have loads of unanswered questions such as 'what if I add my classb and then add a classA with that classb later'

Comment: Also the JSON serialization is another good argument for reducing the complex object to a simple poco class

Comment: I would say POCO means all properties are value types? so your ClassB classb makes it a complex object. change it to string classBId